# How to prevent from plotting outlier in boxplot in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame(called `result_df`) and want to plot one column with boxplot.

But certain outliers spoiled the visualization. How could I prevent from ploting outliers?

Code I used:

```
fig, ax = pl.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(18.5,10.5)
result_df.boxplot(ax=ax)
pl.show()
```

Comment: Figure out what points are outliers, and plot the dataset with those points removed. There is no magical `pd.DataFrame.boxplot_without_outliers` method.

Comment: The above comment by @user554546 is blantly wrong. So just not to have anyone using that "solution": If you remove data from the dataset you change the statistics and hence change the boxplot itself.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Important: I haven't paid enough attention, apparently that happens a lot, and I missed that it's `pandas` specific. However from questions I saw it's basically matplotlib for graphing in the background so this could still work. Sorry I failed to be more careful.

Luckily for you there is such a thing. In the [manual](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot) under `results: dict` title torwards the bottom of the page it states:

> fliers: points representing data that extend beyond the whiskers
>   (outliers).

Setting `showfliers=False` will hopefully help you.

I do have to mention though, that I find it really really strange they shortened outliers to fliers. If that doesn't help [manual](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot) offers a second solution:

> sym : str or None, default = None
>
> The default symbol for flier points. Enter an empty string (‘’) if you don’t want to show fliers. If None, then the fliers default to
>   ‘b+’ If you want more control use the flierprops kwarg.